# Execute Grails Filters in Integration Tests

Tags: grails, groovy, integration-testing, spock

I was through the integration testing documentation for Grails and I noticed this line:

> Grails does not invoke interceptors or servlet filters when calling actions during integration testing.

source: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/testing.html#integrationTesting

1. Why is this?  It would make my testing life a lot easier if Grails did invoke the filters.  My project makes heavy use of filters and many of my controllers depend on my filters in order to do anything.
2. I was thinking about it and it seems like one could use groovy black magic to automatically execute the filters in an integration test.  Has anyone already done this, or is this something that I'd have to write?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The environment used for integration tests is similar to what's available during run-app; Spring is active, plugins are loaded, a database is available, etc. Pretty much everything except for a web server. Without a server, there are no real requests, no servlet filters, and no Grails filters (which are wrappers for Spring controller `HandlerAdaptor`s). When testing controllers you can access a request and response thanks to the Spring servlet API mock classes. But none of the real web request lifecycle is active, it's all just simulated.

You're right that it should be doable with some custom code. When you do this, please consider making it a plugin so we can all share :)